# antlr: grammars not equivalent?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have the following ANTL3 grammar (relevant portion only):

```
from_list
    : from_list_elt (COMMA from_list_elt)*
    ;
```

I need for some reasons that are better left unexplained to rewrite is as

```
from_list
    : from_list_elt 
    | from_list_elt (COMMA from_list_elt)+
    ;
```

which I expect to be equivalent.  However, things that were accepted by the first grammar are refused by the second.  Why is that??

My options:

```
options {
    language=Java;
    backtrack=true;
    memoize=true;
    output=AST;
}
```

Comment: Example? They look to me like they should accept the same language. Only issue I see is that the latter is benignly ambiguous as `from_list_elt` on its own can be accepted by either alternative. Perhaps you meant `+` rather than `*`?

Comment: I just noticed it and replaced * with +, getting the same result.  Producing a self contained example would take a lot of work, the grammar is 2000 lines long...

Comment: do you have somewhere `option k=x` maybe? if yes, it can turn off the ll(*) analysis in favor of classical ll(k) in which the new rule can be ambiguous. but it should also give a warning...

Comment: updated with options.

Comment: options can be rule specific too. if you have `k` set for some subrules of `from_list_elt`, it may still cause trouble for the ll(*) analysis. but I guess this is not the case, otherwise you could see some ambiguity warnings...

Comment: no options, no warnings.

Comment: no idea then :/ take maybe a look at the diff of the generated source files.